# Under what conditions on $f$, is $f(az)=g(a)f(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, factoring

**Formal Statement**

Given nonzero constant $a \in \mathbb{C}$, $|a|>0$ and $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, under what conditions on $f$ does the following hold?

\begin{equation}
    f\left(a z\right) = g\left(a\right) f\left(z\right)
\end{equation}

for some $g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

**Additional Thoughts**

Obviously the above equation holds with $g(a)=a$ when $f$ is a linear function in $z$.

The property I seek seems initially similar to the *separable* property, though that property is typically applied to a multivariate function, and the decomposing functions are new, e.g. $p(x,y)=m(x)n(y)$. Upon closer inspection, this property is really quite different than my question.

1) Is there a general condition on my function $f$ that gives my equality ?

2) Is it possible to determine what the function $g$ is, given $f$ ?

**EDIT I**

1. My condition seems *stricter* than separability in that the same function $f$ appears on the RHS
2. However, my condition is *weaker* than separability in that a is a constant, rather than another complex variable

**EDIT II**

$a$ is indeed a genuine constant. In particular, I only hope to utilize this equation for two values of it:

3. $a=e^{i 2 \pi/3}$
4. $a=e^{i 4 \pi/3}$

Also, perhaps a better iteration of my question is this:

Given nonzero constant $a \in \mathbb{C}$, $|a|>0$ and $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, under what conditions on $f$ does the following hold?

\begin{equation}
    f\left(a z\right) = b f\left(z\right)
\end{equation}

for some $b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Well, one thing you can say is that if $f$ is holomorphic and the $n$-th derivative $f^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$, then $g(a)=a^n$ for all $a$.

Comment: Also, if $\lim_{a\to 0}g(a)$ exists and is non-zero, and if $f$ is holomorphic, then $f$ has to be constant, which would be a contradiction if $f$ is non-zero. So you also can say that if $\lim_{a\to 0}g(a)$ exists, it must approach $0$.

Comment: 2) $g(a)=f(az)/f(z)$. In particular, $g(1)=1$. (But if the equality only holds for a particular $a$, it doesn't make sense to speak of a function $g$.)

Comment: @Steve I don't, but things are generally nicer if it is assumed.

Comment: $g(a)=f(az)/f(z)$ holds only if f(z) is nonzero everywhere.

Comment: If $a$ is a CONSTANT then $g(a)$ is also a constant, no matter what $g$ is. So, I don't know what you really mean with the whole question. Are you asking, for which $a$ and $f$ is there a constant $b$ so that $f(az)$ = $bf(z)$ for all $z$?

Comment: Yes, $a$ is a genuine constant, I'll edit the question. You got it right, I'll be asking, for these particular $a$, what classes of $f$ permit $f(az)  = bf(z)$ for all z and some constant $b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Reworking with logarithms and antilogarithms, you can write the equation as

$$f^*(a+z)=g^*(a)+f^*(z).$$

Then $g^*(a)=f^*(a)-f^*(0)$, implying

$$f^*(a+z)=f^*(a)-f^*(0)+f^*(z),$$ and with $f^+(z)=f^*(z)-f^*(0)$,

$$f^+(a+z)=f^+(a)+f^+(z).$$

If the equation only holds for a single $a$, then with $z=aw$ we have the recurrence

$$f^+(a(w+1))=f^+(aw)+f^+(a)$$ or

$$h(w+1)=h(w)+h(1)$$ for which the solution is easy.

Comment: Indeed, the equation needs only hold for (2) particular values of a, or even 1 may be sufficient, but can you elaborate your solution? I can't follow it, and I don't understand what your conclusion supposedly is.

Comment: Can't you solve that recurrence ?

Comment: @Steve: explained in the post.